# What is the unit of speed values in the static traffic pattern table?

Tags: here-api

I am using the PDE to retrieve the traffic patterns for each link ID for different days and times (https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=NA&release=18133&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=TRAFFIC_PATTERN_FC1). As such, I am referring to the static traffic pattern table to translate the pattern IDs to speeds. For each pattern ID in the table, there exist 4*24 speed values. I am wondering if those values are speeds in kph or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is km/h. You can refer to the static table description for more information. 
https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/scontent?region=WEU&release=18135&url_root=pde.api.here.com&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN

**PATTERN_ID**  ID referenced from the Traffic Pattern layers.
A Pattern ID defines a certain set of speed value across a day.

**SPEED_VALUES**    Average travel speed value for the link in km/h within this time interval during the day.
The 24 * 4 comma separated values correspond to the time 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00 ... 23:45.

Comment: The provided link is not working anymore. This one may have a longer lifetime:
https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/scontent?region=WEU&release=latest&url_root=pde.api.here.com&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN